# How to fill color of an unclosed shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, fill

I want to colour an unclosed shape, to be more precisely what I mean:

Here is where the person creates 2 lines and suddenly he makes the background (fill) green between the 2 lines:

[image]

[Link to original Video](https://youtu.be/_smLXODTd6U?t=27m13s)

I want to do that as well, but I have no idea how...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is treat your open path the same as you would a closed one.

**Click on it, change its fill.**  That simple.

[image]

It works for all sorts of differently shaped paths:

[image]

[image]

After examining the video you posted more closely, I can see you are going about this the wrong way.

**The guy in the video is not filling an open path.**

He is creating green rectangles to fill the space between his outlines.  Look at the image below and you can see the outlines of the paths he used to make the leg/foot:

[image]

Comment: I see, and what about this: |   | with no top and bot line, can this be also coloured? Because the tutor in Youtube video I've posted is coloured the background with only 2 separate vertical paths.

Comment: @Kil'jaeden I edited my post.  It will work for pretty much any shape

Comment: This is what I mean: http://imgur.com/a/ek6EA

Comment: @Kil'jaeden I can tell just by looking at that image that the green is a separate rectangle from the two black lines.

Comment: @Kil'jaeden I updated my answer again, you might want to look

Comment: Ah thanks... so that's how he did... now I feel kinda stupid for overthinking "Gap Technique". Thanks for clearing it up... I was watching all kind of gap colouring videos in hope to find the answer. Very awesome of you to make those animated answers they are really helpful.